# Hausdorff measure on non separable spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

In his book `Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces`, Pertti Mattila defines the Hausdorff measures via the Carathéodory's construction (chap.4). My doubt is that the Carathéodory's construction is done on a general metric space, while the definition of Hausdorff measure is given starting from a separable space. I personally don't see where separability comes into play. Is it necessary for some reason or we could just keep reasoning on a general metric space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your estimates of $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of a set $E$, you have to do this:  For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose a countable cover $\{U_k\}$ of $E$ with $\text{diam}\; U_k < \epsilon$ for all $k$.  Then your estimate is
$$
\sum_k \left(\text{diam}\; U_k\right)^s
\tag{$*$}
$$
You take the infimum over all covers.  Then the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.  This is the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal H^s(E)$.

Now suppose $E$ is non-separable.  Then for small enough $\epsilon > 0$ there is no countable cover by sets of diameter ${}\lt \epsilon$.  Then you have an infimum over the empty set of the numbers ($*$), and we get $+\infty$.  And so limit for $\epsilon \to 0$ is also $+\infty$.

Result.  For any non-separable set $E$ and for any $s \in [0,+\infty)$, we have Hausdorff measure $\mathcal H^s(E) = +\infty$.  And therefore the Hausdorff dimension of $E$ is $+\infty$.

So, if you like, you **can** define Hausdorff measures for non-separable sets.  But it turns out to be uninteresting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually Mattila, when describing the Carathéodory's construction, starts from a couple of assumption that can be phrased as "there are covers with sets of arbitrarily small diameter" and "the empty set have measure $0$". In particular the first one is made exactly to avoid the possibility of not having covers. I understand that separability implies the first condition but the converse needs not to be true, hence I would say that the first condition is actually what we are looking for if we want the definition to be interesting.

Comment: I also understand that often we just work with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we don't care much about the rest!

Comment: So prove this equivalence for metric spaces.  (a) For every $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable cover by sets of diameter ${}\le \epsilon$.  (b) There is a countable dense set.  You said you understand (a) $\Leftarrow$ (b).  So you now should investigate (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b).

Comment: Does the implication $(a)\Rightarrow (b)$ requires the axiom of choice? I could not come up with a proof that does not require it